# Implementing Web Crawler on a distributed architecture in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, distributed-computing

Friends, I have implemented a multi threaded Web Crawler in Java . In order to make it more efficient I want to convert  it into distributed architecture i.e on 3 machines. As far as i have searched master-slave architecture is best. Can anyone provide some insight into  Which is the best architecture and how i can implement it in Java?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [twitter storm](http://storm-project.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You could compute hashcode for each domain being crawled and use this hash to determine which node should crawl that domain. That way all nodes could work in parallel without much interaction.

You also need some code to merge the crawled results after the crawling is complete, or periodically. Probably also it is better just to copy some produced archives from the nodes and process in a central location.

A cloud of virtual machines looks like a good deployment platform as crawling is not very CPU or memory intensive.